# Vue preselect value with select, v-for, and v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `select` with `v-model` and have options with `v-for` and object as a value. Options are some elements identified by id. How do I make option preselected based on custom equality (in this case by equal `id` field)? I'm looking for something similar to angularjs' `track by` from `ng-options`.

https://jsfiddle.net/79wsf1n4/5/

How to make the input preselected with the value with equal id?

template:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in inventory" :value="item" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <p>
    {{ selected.id }}
  </p>
</div>
```

js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', id: 1},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', id: 2},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', id: 3},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', id: 4}
    ],
    selected: {
        id: 2
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Careful with the comma : `:value="item",  :key="item.id"` (delete it !)

Comment: @SLYcee Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add the selected attribute as per Dharmendra's answer.

The issue however is that you're not assigning a valid object to your selected property. Vue will try to look for an identical object in your option list, it will do this by object equality comparison.

At this time I'm not aware whether it's possible to tell Vue to base the initial selection on an attribute, however a very simple solution is to assign the selected property based on the ID yourself in the created lifecycle callback:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', id: 1},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', id: 2},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', id: 3},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', id: 4}
    ],
    selected: 2
  },
  created: function() {
        this.selected = this.inventory.find(i => i.id === this.selected);
  }
});
```

I've updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79wsf1n4/3/) as well.

Comment: That's a possible solution but what I'm looking for exactly is to base the initial selection on an attribute. If that's not possible then i will have to use this.

Comment: From what I can tell from the docs, this isn't possible without adding own code to handle the lookup. You could request this feature to be added at the Vue GitHub page.

Comment: @thomaux I've a question here, if `selected` value is an array how can i do this ??. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the way you are assigning value to option. change this `:value="item"` to `v-bind:value="item"`.

HTML part

```
<select class="form-control" name="template" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in inventory" v-bind:value="item">
       {{ item.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

JS part

```
new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data: {
    ...
    selected: {name: 'MacBook Pro', id: 2}
  }
})
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dspoonia7/402muqre/4/)

Comment: You don't need this code `:selected="item.id == defaultItem.id ? 'selected' : ''"`. Because you use `v-model` the value is directly bind to the option value.

Comment: Sorry, upvoted to early. `selected` option works only with vue 1.0 and doesn't with vue 2.0. Unfortunately making selected just an id is not an option for me. I'm looking for a way to make that work with an object as a value.

Comment: It works with `Vue.js v2.2.0`. Kindly check the Vue version in the http://jsfiddle.net/dspoonia7/d9f9tj4n/2/.

Comment: I was saying that `:selected="item.id == defaultItem.id ? 'selected' : ''"` doesn't work with v2. The solution you provided does indeed work, however as I said I need the whole object as a v-model, not just id.

Comment: Hey This works http://jsfiddle.net/dspoonia7/402muqre/3/ Using whole object. Cheers!!

Comment: It's ok, but it's because the whole object is identical, this also won't always be the case in my situation. But yeah, that's working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code you don't need but useful to test the behavior (in your case you need to set `initSelect` with `id` or `name`) :

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', id: 1},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', id: 2},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', id: 3},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', id: 4}
    ],
    initSelect : {
     id: 2
    },
    selected: {},
  },
  created: function() {
    this.setSelectedWithInit();
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedWithInit: function() {
      var firstKey = Object.keys(this.initSelect)[0],
         value = this.initSelect[firstKey];
      
      for( var i = 0, length = this.inventory.length; i < length; i++ ) {
       if( (this.inventory[i].hasOwnProperty(firstKey))
         && (this.inventory[i][firstKey] === value) )
        {
          this.selected = this.inventory[i];
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    toggle: function() {//you don't need this method
      if( this.initSelect.hasOwnProperty('id') ) {
        this.initSelect = { name: 'Lenovo W530' };
      } else {
        this.initSelect = { id: 2 };
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'initSelect': {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        this.setSelectedWithInit();
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-instance">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in inventory" :value="item" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <p>
    {{ initSelect.id }}
    {{ initSelect.name }}
  </p>
  
  <!-- You don't need the rest of the html below -->
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle id/name</button>
  
  <div v-if="initSelect.hasOwnProperty('id')">
    Id: <input v-model.number="initSelect.id" type="number">
  </div>
  
  <div v-else>
    Name: <input v-model="initSelect.name" type="text">
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  {{ initSelect }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I know that having identical object will work, however that's not always be the case in my application. Therefore I'm looking for a way to specify a single attribute for equality check.

Comment: @TuanPham I updated my answer. This is what you need (change the `selected` by `id` or `name`) ?