# <V-Model> doesn't work inside <V-Select> and only give no data available

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

lets say i want to make 2 text field and 1 v-select in vuejs using vuetify

- Comodity ID (v-model = id)
- Comodity Name (v-model = name)
- v-select (v-model = selectType, :item= ['Using Document ID', id])

but whenever i try using the data such as `this.id` or `id` `v-select` always return `No data available`

I tried some of this topic but it doesn't solve my problem:

[Vue Preselect Value with Select, v-for, and v-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366723/vue-preselect-value-with-select-v-for-and-v-model)

[Vue dynamic v-model within v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854385/vue-dynamic-v-model-within-v-for)

[Vue JS - Bind select option value to model inside v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404552/vue-js-bind-select-option-value-to-model-inside-v-for)

this is my code :

```
<v-flex lg12 sm12>
 <v-text-field label="Kode Penjualan" name="kodePenjualan" v-model="kodePenjualan">
 </v-text-field>
</v-flex>

<v-flex lg12 sm12>
 <v-text-field label="Komoditas" name="komoditas" v-model="komoditas">
 </v-text-field>
</v-flex>

<v-flex lg12 sm12>
 <v-select
  v-model="selectDocs"
  :items="tipeDocs"
  label="Dokumen yang Dimiliki"
 ></v-select>
</v-flex>
```

this is my script:

```
data: () => ({
 kodePenjualan: null,
 komoditas: null,
 selectDocs: null,
 tipeDocs: [
   'Dokumen Usaha Dagang Perantara',      
   kodePenjualan
 ],  
}),
```

this is what i got right now

[image: This is What I got Right Now]

This is what i want to achieved

[image: This is What I want to achieved]

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve this, it seems i must computed `tipeDocs` properly to update my own `:items`,

```
computed: {
  tipeDocs() {
    return [
      'Dokumen Usaha Dagang Perantara',
      this.kodePenjualan
    ]
  }
}
```

I hope this solution can help a lot of people who got stuck at the same problem with me

source : [Answer for my question in Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-doesnt-work-inside-v-select-and-only-give-no-data-available/61005)